# Replace space with hyphen using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

My URLs currently look like `www.example.com/explore/above%20&%20beyond`

I want a SEO friendly URL like `www.example.com/explore/above-and-beyond`

Here is my **urls.py**

```
url(r'^explore/(?P<dj_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-]+)/$', views.explore_dj, name='explore_dj')
```

How can I replace `%20` with `-` and `&` with `and` in the URLs using regular expressions?

I know ideally I should be using `SlugField` for this, but I'll have to drop my database tables for making the changes to my Models and that isn't an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I would do in this case is the following. If you're not insisting on using a regexp, you might want to consider it.

```
'www.example.com/explore/above%20&%20beyond'.replace('%20','-').replace('&','and')
```

Comment: This is definitely faster than regexp.

Comment: I have tried adding this in urls.py, but no luck. For example I have:  url(r'^view/(?P<event_name>[\w\s]+)$'.replace('%20','-')... Is this where the code should be?

Answer (score -1):

`re.sub(r'&','and',re.sub(r'%20','-',url_string))`

```
>>> url_string = 'www.example.com/explore/above%20&%20beyond'
>>> url_string
'www.example.com/explore/above%20&%20beyond'
>>> re.sub(r'&','and',re.sub(r'%20','-',url_string))
'www.example.com/explore/above-and-beyond'
```

Comment: I don't have the URLs available as a string as I'm using Django. I did `re.sub(r'&','and',re.sub(r'%20','-', r'^top100/(?P<dj_name>[a-zA-Z0-9 \'&-]+)/$'))` and it gives me the error `Reverse for 'dj' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'dj_name': u'Dimitri Vegas & Like Mike'}' not found.` meaning this doesn't work with the DJ's with `&` in the name.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't speak Django. Is this the place where you can customize/map URLs?

Comment: Yes, this is where you customize the URLs.

Comment: What does the `name` parameter of `url` do? How would you ordinarily change the page URL (for a static change, not any sort of substitution)?